# Angular Site That Runs Locally, Doesn't On Azure Web App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have purchased the Altair Material Design Template from Code Canyon -

> http://themeforest.net/item/altair-material-design-premium-template/full_screen_preview/12190654

I can run the AngularJS version fine when viewing the files on my Mac desktop... However, when I upload it to an Azure Web App, it no longer works:

> http://mrtaltair.azurewebsites.net/#/

The page seems to get stuck in the pre-loader, rather than loading the dashboard (which it does when reading the index file on my desktop).

I've purchased the theme as I'm a bit of a learner driver & wanted something that was quick & easy to load.  Could anyone explain whats going on?

Comment: With just a quick look I can see that your Azure site has files throwing 404 errors (not found) on load. If they are critical to your site loading scripts, it will prevent the page from ever displaying. I would start with getting those resolved and go from there.

Comment: Thanks @buzzsaw - although I'm not seeing any 404 errors in the console - https://www.dropbox.com/s/nj474txd8un35vl/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-01%20at%2023.34.06.png?dl=0

Comment: must not be looking in right place in console

Comment: I get no 404 errors on any files.  I get some 304 messages when I do a network check using the Firefox Network tool in Inspect Element.

Comment: user_data.json, mg_dashboard_chart.min.json, and package.json are all 404's in the Firefox network tab.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you are looking in the console tab, not the network tab.

Comment: Hi @buzzsaw I've looked at both - https://www.dropbox.com/s/iq034phwcprie8a/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-01%20at%2023.52.11.png?dl=0

Comment: @buzzsaw are you definitely seeing 404 errors?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing them on these URL's.
http://mrtaltair.azurewebsites.net/data/mg_dashboard_chart.min.json, http://mrtaltair.azurewebsites.net/data/user_data.json, http://mrtaltair.azurewebsites.net/package.json

Comment: Ah.  Me too when I click on the links.  Let me look into whats going on with them...

Comment: The permissions are set to 777 & I can't see the files.  I've tried 2 hosts (Azure & Godaddy), both not visible.  I have noticed that the Google Maps authenticate service keeps flagging up...(which won't have a valid token as I haven't inserted one).

Comment: I'm going back to the developer on this, as I'm sure its something to do with the template rather than the hosting.  I'll post the solution on here.

Comment: if it works fine on your local version why would it be developer's issue? You are either missing files on server or have a configuration problem

Comment: True point.  There are clearly some permission issues as the ftp is indicating a clear replication of the desktop files.  Are there any specific Azure permission issues/config that any of you are aware of?

Comment: OK, so I've had another look at the Godaddy hosted version of the site & it was missing a directory.  It now works (tiredness kills...).  So, there is an issue reading JSON on Azure.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here was that the .json files weren't readable as discovered by @buzzsaw.  The files were present, & permissions set to read the files.  I fixed the issue by adding a web.config file as per this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website.aspx